# Overflow hidden for a heading tag not working on mobile browsers, Chrome and Safari. Only works on desktop browsers

Tags: html, css, overflow, hidden

[screenshots of desktop working vs. mobile not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DjLn.jpg)

I have a code snippet to show what I'm trying to do. I have intentionally set a wider width to a heading that is inside a div containing a slideshow. I want the width of the heading to be clipped by the rounded edge of the image. I have something similar working on desktop browsers, but it doesn't render in Safari or Chrome on my iphone. I had set overflow: hidden to the parent div, which did hide the outer parts of the heading like I intended. But I can't get it to render properly on mobile devices. (Note: overflow hidden is hiding everything in the snippet, and I'm not sure what's going on there either).

I have researched similar questions, but those seem to be dealing with overflow issues concerning the body of an entire page.

```css
div {
   position: relative;
   /* overflow: hidden; */
}
h3 {
   margin: 0;
   z-index: 4;
   width: 300px;
   height: 20px;
   position: absolute;
 /* top: 150px; */
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}
img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 3;
   animation: slideshow 12s linear 0s infinite;
   border-radius: 25px;
}

img:nth-child(2) {
   z-index: 2;
   animation-delay: 4s;
}

img:nth-child(3) {
   z-index: 1;
   animation-delay: 8s;
}

@keyframes slideshow {
   25% {
      opacity: 1;
   }
   33.33% {
      opacity: 0;
   }
   91.66% {
      opacity: 0;
   }
   100% {
      opacity: 1;
   }
}
```

```html
<div>
<h3>Slideshow</h3>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/280x200/56AD30/fff.png&text=1" />
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/280x200/1560f0/fff.png&text=2" />
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/280x200/C03229/fff.png&text=3" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see it now that you added the images. You have a margin problem there. The h3 element adds margin. If you add 'margin: 0' to your h3 style you will see what happens. One more thing, you need to remove 'top: 150px;'. 
And you have to put some working code next time. In the example you added you cannot see anything at least you add a height value to the main div.

Comment: Where do you suggest I add the height value? I posted an edit with a screenshot of the overflow working on my desktop vs. mobile

Comment: I followed your suggestions, but that heading needs to sit at the bottom of the image. I also hid overflow, just so you can see something. But I need that heading to be clipped by the image.